# Are there domain restrictions on simplexml reads from third party websites

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I have a pretty simple question. I am a newbie so please forgive if too basic.

If I run the following script on my localhost server (apache/mamp) it runs fine and gives me the current temperature for a certain location. If I upload it to my site, it doesn't run. Cant figure it out. Maybe someone can help. Thanks. I am using a network solutions domain server, shared hosting.

```
<?php
    $myFeed = simplexml_load_file('http://w1.weather.gov/xml/current_obs/KAND.xml');
    $temperature =  ($myFeed->temp_f) . " F ";
    echo $temperature;
?>
```

Comment: Do you have error reporting activated? You should be getting error messages

Answer (score 0):

Your most likely problem here is [the `allow_url_fopen` setting](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen). This may be set to off by your host, or they may have related restrictions in place.

Note that it is not SimpleXML that is placing this restriction - the `simplexml_load_file` is mainly designed to act on a local file path. The PHP "file system wrappers" allow you to use a URL as though it was the path to a local file and download it automatically, but only if configured to allow this.

To work around this, look for an example of using "CURL" to explicitly fetch the content from the URL into a string, and then load it with `simplexml_load_string`